# Python and PyWinAuto version installation on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I am confused about the following:

1. My OS is windows 7 64 bit, the application that I am trying to automate using python is a 32 bit application. Now should I install Python 64 bit or 32 bit?
2. My application is a windows application(not web), so I am trying to install the PyWinAuto. PyWinAuto Installation document in silent mode says "(Python 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5)". So this means PyWinAuto is supported only till Python version 3.5?
3. I then installed Python 3.5.3 (64 bit), installed PyWinAuto using the silent installation command (pip install pywinauto), but when I tried to check if I have installed correctly by starting notepad.exe as explained in the document, the notepad just opened and vanished in a second.
4. I want to able to perform commands on my application's wpf controls using automation id's which I am able to fetch using the inspect tool. So is this possible using PyWinAuto? I looked into the controls but most are related to the control of objects using coordinates etc. If I have object id, can I use it in all the control functions available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd recommend to read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). It answers many of your questions and explains the core concept.

1. If you use Win32 API based backend (`Application(backend='win32')` or just `Application()`), it's important to install 32-bit Python and use it for 32-bit applications (from 64-bit Python you can crash the app). But for `backend='uia'` it doesn't matter. Since you're trying to automate WPF app, use `backend='uia'` as explained in the Getting Started Guide.
2. Pywinauto is auto-tested on Python 3.6 as well. See [AppVeyor build matrix](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/pywinauto/pywinauto/build/0.6.0_build857). So no problem to use Py3.6.
3. Please describe the problem in more details. What the code do you run? From what document did you get it? Maybe it's outdated pywinauto-0.5.4 docs?
4. Again, the Getting Started Guide explains how to find `Inspect.exe` (Spy tool from Windows SDK) which can show you all WPF controls. Pywinauto supports almost all complicated WPF lists, grids etc. We have many auto-tests using a WPF sample application. Automation ids can be used as well. Method `print_control_identifiers()` often shows `auto_id='<id>'` criterion in a window specification for the controls which have such ids.

Comment: Hi Vasily, Thank you for your reply !

Comment: As per your comment, I have installed Python 3.6 for my 32 bit application. I am referring to the following document - https://pywinauto.github.io/docs/                                                            1) When I try to install pywinauto using the pip install pywinauto, I am getting the error "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." 2) So I installed Python 3.5.3 and installed PyWinAuto, it installed successfully. 3) After installation, I tried the code

Comment: from pywinauto.application import Applicationapp = Application().start("notepad.exe")
>>> app.UntitledNotepad.TypeKeys("%FX")

Comment: Sorry for the above post, it is not complete.  I tried the code.                from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
app.UntitledNotepad.TypeKeys("%FX")

Comment: First, you use old docs for pywinauto 0.5.4 as I said previously. The most recent docs are in the Getting Started Guide (I wrote it specially for 0.6.0+ releases). And yes, `"%FX"` means `Alt+F+X` which closes Notepad immediately by choosing `File->Exit` menu item. It's expected behavior. :) You can check it manually.

Comment: If `pip` is not available, probably you need to install this Python as a default and check option `Add it to PATH variable` in the Python installer. Or add `C:\Python36\Scripts` to PATH manually. Or call `C:\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe install -U pywinauto` using full path to pip.exe.

Comment: Thank you again Vasily ! So I will refer the Getting Started Guide as mentioned by you. Please excuse me for silly questions.

Comment: No problem. I'm here to help. :)
If my answer is correct and complete, please mark it as accepted (grayed check box under voting buttons should work for you). It's considered polite on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sure Vasily ! Please tell me where I should look for the voting button and I shall click on accepted right away !

Comment: Do you see "Vote up" and "Vote down" button at the left side of the answer? The check box should be below them.

Comment: Hi Vasily ! I really need your help !! I managed to install python 3.5.3 (32 bit) and pywinauto. I have started going through the getting started guide mentioned by you. I have one major doubt !! Please help me with this. I am using the inspect tool. I have launched the application using the code : from pywinauto import Application
app = Application().start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Trane\TRACE 3D Plus\TRACE™ 3D Plus.exe"). Now as I understood to tell python what the window is we use the : dlg = app['TRACE™ 3D Plus'].

Comment: In this screen, I have value for automation id and class name using the inspect tool.  Please tell me the syntax for clicking on that button using the automation id. For example, a button on my application has the automation id "Airflows" which is seen in the inspect tool. Now how am I to click on this using python ?

Comment: This is another question. You can ask it separately. And please don't expect help from others if you don't accept correct answers. Thank you for understanding. P.S. It's possible to use automation id in pywinauto.

Comment: Hi vasily , like you said, I did not see a accepted button like you said

Comment: Else I would have clicked on it long back..I shall post it as a separate question too..

Comment: Oh yes !! I installed the stack overflow app and I see the tick. Clicking it now !!

Comment: Please tell me me if you can see that I have accepted it now.

Comment: Now it's OK. Thanks! Please re-ask if you're in doubt about StackOverflow features. The answer on your question is in the Getting Started Guide also. When you call `.print_control_identifiers()` method you can copy paste `child_window` statements to your code. Example: `app.TopLevelWindow.child_window(auto_id='Airflows').invoke()`

Comment: Hi Vasily, As I mentioned in the comment for this question which was posted separately,  I guess app.print_control_identifiers() is not working for me. Could it be because I have installed pywinauto incorrectly ? It throws a timeouterror, window not found etc.